# How to make my sound card produce sounds using Python?

Tags: python

I want to produce sounds/beeps from my sound card using Python. Is it possible? If so, how? (Using Linux)

Comment: [First result](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio) for "Python sound" on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does not have a cross-platform way to play sounds.

When speaking about Linux, there is this interesting library [`ossauiodev`](http://docs.python.org/library/ossaudiodev.html). The code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125547/how-to-play-sound-in-python-without-interrupting-music-other-sounds-from-playing) may be considered as example code, but the question shows that the library is not perfect.

You could use some external library, such as [*pygame*](http://pygame.org/) ([example](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=567722)) or *Qt*'s [*Phonon*](https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/phonon/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to beep, print the [bell character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character):

```
print '\a'
```

Of course this only gives you one type of sound, so if you need something more complex check out [the link](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio) Michael put in comments.  Alternatives to `'\a'` are `chr(7)` and `'\x07'`.

Comment: Depends on your terminal emulator.